# Accounts problem

Tags: gmail, accounts

Using Gmail, if I click on the 3 horizontals bars top left, near Inbox, on top I see my primary account (a) with an arrow on the right.  If I click on this arrow, I see 2 secondary accounts (b) & (c).

Going back to my inbox, I want to reply to an email using address (b).  I click reply and the arrow next to my primary address.  There I see: send email as (d) or (e) - i.e. 2 other secondary addresses that I had created very long ago.

My questions are:
1. how can I remove (d) & (e)?
2. how can I see (b) & (c) instead?

If I go to Settings/Accounts/Google, I only see (a), (b) & (c).  (d) & (e) don't appear, therefore I can't remove them.

Thank you in advance for your help

(Android 6.0 but I had this problem before this version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else has the same problem, I solved it by going to Gmail on my laptop: Using my main account (a), 'Settings > Accounts and Import > Send Mail As' Only (d) & (e) were there. I added (b) & (c)

Comment: If this worked for you, you should tick your answer (Since you answered your own question) so it does't remain in the unanswered section and so other users who have the same problem know of a solution.